# Deployment of C# Project with Local Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a C# application with local database `.mdf` files.Its all finished.But I am badly stuck where I want to run my .exe file in clients pc.I have searched  a lot but totally confused what to do.Mostly everyone has used  a SQL server.This is my first project so I don't know the things quite well.I have used visual studio 2015 and I have made a local database in server explorer.

Their .MDF and log.ldf files are made and stored in the path:

```
(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=
C:\Users\SONY\Documents\DATAENTRY.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30");
```

How can I transfer the `.exe` file and `.mdf` files in my clients machine however I have didn't use any SQL server.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can install sql server in the client machine and import the dbf which is available in your local machine and run .exe

Answer (score 1):

you have to install LocalDB through the installation wizard or by using the SqlLocalDB.msi program on the client computer. This may solve this issue

[For More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb)

Comment: And do I have to make a same path of mdf files in client machine?